# Static analysis on a dynamically typed language

Tags: python, static-analysis, dynamic-typing

I was reading http://tratt.net/laurie/research/pubs/html/tratt__dynamically_typed_languages/#x1-50002.3 and it explains that static analysis is not practical approach on a dynamically typed language but the reasons are not very clear. My question is why is static analysis on very practical on a dynamically typed language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that `cond(y)` is a Boolean-valued function.  Suppose that in you have the line

```
x = "Hello World" if cond(y) else [1,2,3]
```

Where `y` is some other variable. How could any static analysis tell if `x` was a string or a list of integers? `y` isn't known at compile time. The only way to tell is to run the program -- which defeats the purpose of static analysis

A more realistic example:

```
def squareRoot(x):
    if x > 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return (0,math.sqrt(abs(x))) #representing complex a+bi as (a,b)
```

this returns either a float or an int,float pair. Thus there is no well-defined returned value. How is static analysis supposed to handle functions of indeterminate return type?

This sort of consideration places a severe restriction on what a static analyzer could hope to accomplish with a dynamically typed language. This *doesn't* imply that all static analysis of such languages is impossible or worthless. In fact, there are static analysis tools for Python, with [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) being the most developed. Even there, though, it is surprising how few of Pylint's [errors and warnings](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-messages) are specifically about *type errors* (such as trying to add a string and an integer). Instead, almost all the error and warning codes are more along the lines of `"assigning to function call which doesn't return"`.

Comment: By passing a type "any" where it doesn't know, and tighter type bounds where it does know.   It might not be able to reason about particular bit of code, but most programmers don't write code they don't understand.  One should be able to build a static analyzer for Python.  It might not understand a lot.  Where it did understand what was happening, it is likely to reasonably well.

Comment: @IraBaxter I was explaining what is behind the linked to paper's statement to the effect that static analysis (defined in the paper as a tool for catching all violations of type constraints before run time) isn't practical in dynamically typed languages. The claim isn't that it is impossible to do any static analysis, just that it isn't practical to do a full-fledged static analysis of an entire program, one which determines the type of every expression and variable at compile time. Still, you raise a good point. I'll edit to include a caveat. Thank you.

Comment: `How could any static analysis tell if x was a string or a list of integer` it could easily assign x an union type of string and list of integers, and give meaningful errors where its use is incompatible with both options.